# How to interpret a "Show that the relation R consisting of all pairs(x,y)..."?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the relation R consisting of all pairs (x, y) such that x and y are bit strings of length three or more that agree in their first three bits is an equivalence relation on the set of all bit strings of length three or more

What I see is that they want me to make a relation with pairs of 001 or 011 etc inside for both but the relation must be transitive,reflexive and symmetric. But when I searched for an answer and found a similar question.

"Show that the relation R consisting of all pairs (x, y) such that x and y are bit strings of length three or more that agree.except perhaps on their first three bits is an equivalence relation on the set of all bit strings of length three or more."

with an answer it just wrote

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Why didn't They didn't make a relation and just assumed it was reflexive even tho in their question it says "except perhaps in their first three bits" which would make it not reflexive?

Why for checking for symmetry why is it that they have "Agree except perhaps in their first three bits" as if they know but that it doesn't matter and is symmetric anyway?

Why could it be transitive if perhaps in their first three bits?

What does the word "agree" do for this question?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: This relation is of a very common type of equivalence relations: let $x \sim y$ if $f(x) = f(y)$. In this case $f(x)$ gives the first three bits of the bit string $x$.

Answer (score 0):

'Agree' in that other question means that the two bit strings are the same for all bits that come after the first three.  The 'except perhaps' means that the first three digits may or may not be the same, it doesn't matter as far as the relation goes.

So, you would have $xRy$ if and only if bit strings $x$ and $y$ are bit strings of a length of 3 or more, and whose bits after the first three are exactly the same.

This $R$ is reflexive because any bit string $x$ will have the exact same bits after the first three.

It is symmetric because if $x$ and $y$ are bit strings of a length of 3 or more, and whose bits after the first three are exactly the same, then $y$ and $x$ have the same bits after the first three as well.

And finally, $R$ is transitive, since if $x$ and $y$ are bit strings of a length of 3 or more, and whose bits after the first three are exactly the same, and $y$ and $zy$ are bit strings of a length of 3 or more, and whose bits after the first three are exactly the same, then $x$ and $z$ are bit strings of a length of 3 or more, and whose bits after the first three are exactly the same.